# I need to sort the elements of the stack randomly

Tags: c, stack

I need to sort the elements of the stack randomly in `PILA_centrifugar` function. I have this code to create the stack. I need to implement in `PILA_centrifugar` this functionality.

```
Pila PILA_crea() {
    Pila p;

    p = NULL;

    return p;
}

void PILA_push(Pila *p, int elemento) {
    Nodo *aux;
    aux = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    if (aux == NULL) {
        printf("No se puede hacer push ");
    } else {
        aux->elemento = elemento;
        aux->sig = *p;
        *p = aux;
    }
}

void PILA_pop(Pila *p) {
    Nodo *aux;

    if (*p == NULL) {
        printf("\nError al hacer pop");
    } else {
        aux = *p;
        *p = (*p)->sig;
        free(aux);
    }
}

void PILA_centrifugar(Pila *p) {
    Nodo *aux;

    if (*p == NULL) {
        printf("\nError centrifugar");
    } else {
        aux = *p;
        *p = rand();
        free(aux);
    }
}
```

Comment: By "sort randomly" do you mean "shuffle"?

Comment: Yes, i need to shuffle the stack.

Comment: You appear to have a LIFO structure. Can you make a FIFO structure and pass items around between the 2 structures?

Comment: You must post the definitions for `Pila` and `Node`. `*p = rand();` seems incorrect, a type mismatch.